# Concatenate two pandas DataFrames without duplicating row ids?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `pandas` `DataFrames`. They have the same columns, and so I want to take the data from each and put it into a larger `DataFrame`. The issue is that the number that identifies each row is copied verbatim, while I want it to update intelligently.

Here's what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

df_one = pd.DataFrame([
    {'animal': 'cat', 'color': 'black'},
    {'animal': 'dog', 'color': 'brown'}])
df_two = pd.DataFrame([
    {'animal': 'fish', 'color': 'red'},
    {'animal': 'bird', 'color': 'blue'}])

print(pd.DataFrame([df_one, df_two]))
```

Which outputs:

```
  animal  color
0 cat     black
1 dog     brown
0 fish    red
1 bird    blue
```

The output I want is:

```
  animal  color
0 cat     black
1 dog     brown
2 fish    red
3 bird    blue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `concat` with `ignore_index=True`:

```
>>> pandas.concat([df_one, df_two], ignore_index=True)
  animal  color
0    cat  black
1    dog  brown
2   fish    red
3   bird   blue
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @BrenBarn's answer. You could alternately do:

```
>>> df_concat = pd.concat([df_one, df_two]).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df_concat
  animal  color
0    cat  black
1    dog  brown
2   fish    red
3   bird   blue
```